# DynamoDB one-to-many relation denormalization or adjacency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am designing a table for a data structure that represents a business operation that can be performed either ad hoc or as part of a batch. Operations that are performed together as a batch must be linked and queryable, and there is meta data on the batch that will be persisted.

The table must support 2 queries: retrieve history, both ad hoc and batch instances.

Amazon suggests 2 approaches, **adjacency** and **denormalization**.

I am not sure which approach is best. Speed will be a priority, cost secondary.
This will be a multi-tenant database with multiple organizations with million+ operations. (Orgs will be a part of partition key to segregated these across nodes)

Here are the ideas I've come up with:

- Denormalized, non adjacency - single root wrapper object with 1 (ad hoc) or more (batch) operation data.
- Denormalized, adjacency - top level keys consist of operation instances (ad hoc) as well as parent objects containing collection of operation instances (batch)
- Normalized, non adjacency, duplicate data - top level consists of operations instances, with or without a batch key, abd batch information duplicated among all members of batch

Is there a standard best practice? Any advice on setting up/generating keys?

Comment: I am not really sure where did you get those approaches, adjacency & demoralization. Never heard of these. It would be better if you can describe in another way like :
1. what is the sample you have?
2. what is the sample data to be input output?

Comment: and dynamodb is NoSQL DB model, so there is no concept of de/:normalization and relational table

Comment: These links describe the 2 approaches: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html, https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it confuses me to understand the concept with these terms in NoSQL most specific DynamoDB. For me, hard to design the dynamodb table based on piece by piece of the whole business process. And precisely, I am more worried to data sizes instead of the speed in DynamoDB request due to we have 1MB limit per request. In other words, I should forget all things about relational DB concept and see the data as json object when working with dynamodb.

But well, for very simple one-to-many (i.e person loves some fruits) design I will have my best scheme choice has String PartitionKey. So my table will be like so :

```
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|     PartitionKey    |                Infos                  |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|       PersonID      | {name:String, age:Number, loveTo:map} |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|       FruitID       | {name:String, otherProps}             |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
```

The sample data :

```
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|     PartitionKey    |                Infos                  |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|      person123      | {                                     |
|                     |  name:"Andy",                         | 
|                     |  age:24,                              |
|                     |  loveTo:["fruit123","fruit432"]       |
|                     | }                                     |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|      personABC      | {                                     |
|                     |  name:"Liza",                         | 
|                     |  age:20,                              |
|                     |  loveTo:["fruit432"]                  |
|                     | }                                     |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|      fruit123       | {                                     |
|                     |  name:"Apple",                        | 
|                     |  ...                                  |
|                     | }                                     |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
|      fruit432       | {                                     |
|                     |  name:"Manggo",                       | 
|                     |  ...                                  |
|                     | }                                     |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------|
```

But let's see more complex case, for the sample chat app. Each channel allows many users, Each user is possible to join in any channels. Whether it should be one-to-many or many-to-many and how to make the relation? I will say I don't care about them. If we think as like relational DB, what a headache! In this case I will have composite SortKey and even Secondary Index to speedup the specific query.

> So, the question what's the whole business process you work on will
> help us to design the table, not piece by piece

Comment: In your schema above, I would need fruits to belong to a person and the need to query all a persons fruit as well as specific fruit based on a property. I have found that doing this as Fruits being a collection under people, update options are limited and costly for Fruit.

Comment: "I would need fruits to belong to a person" you can do that with above scheme. "query all a persons fruit as well as specific fruit based on a property" you need add SortKey with prefix. "update options are limited and costly for Fruit" I don't get it what you mean